# How to integrate apache-nutch-1.9 and Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.1.0?

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I'm very new to `nutch` and was trying to integrate `nutch 1.9` with `Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.1.0` and getting exceptions like below:

```
Injector: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:167)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:297)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:370)
```

I have few questions about this:
How do i solve this issue. Also I had question in mind if I can really integrate the version of `hadoop` which I am using to `nutch 1.9`?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Same issue with Nutch 2.2.1